# Does Docker virtualization improve stability?

Tags: virtualization, crash, docker

I read somewhere maybe a year ago, that using Docker containers make a server more stable, because the container will crash instead of the host OS by a malfunctioning application.

As far as I know, [applications cannot crash an OS by themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114081/common-causes-of-operating-system-crashes), they need some kernel, driver or hardware bug to do so.

Does Docker virtualization prevent host OS crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtualization does not prevent host OS crashes, but it may help in lowering
the risk factor.

Docker is nothing but an interface which translates system calls from
the virtualized program to the host OS.
Therefore one or a combination of the calls can still hit an OS bug
and crash it.

Docker is in this way more liable to cause such problems than
classical virtual machines, as the virtualized program is less isolated
under Docker, although the likelihood of this happening
under Docker is maybe somewhat less than when running directly on the OS,
because the calls go through two interfaces rather than one
and so are doubly checked.

Docker does place some limits on the virtualized program,
such as maximum RAM and CPU,
which may help to avoid system crashes because of
overload and resource saturation.
It also hides the host's file system from the virtualized program
(exceptions always possible),
therefore avoiding its corruption by the program.

Comment: Is the same true for LXC containers and virtual machines?